JDBC settings not applied when deploying from SonarQube Helm Chart
I'm trying to get SonarQube web server to connect to a backend DB in RDS instead of local.

SonarQube version: 10.4.1 community edition.
Scanner: sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.7.1.2311-net46\SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe
Plugins: N.A.
Deployment method: Helm deploying to AWS EKS with external postgres DB on AWS RDS

$ helm upgrade --debug --install sonarqube --namespace sandbox --create-namespace -f values.yaml sonarqube/sonarqube

values.yaml:

image:
  tag: 10.4.1-{{ .Values.edition }}

persistence:
  enabled: true
  storageClass: "gp2"
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 30Gi
  uid: 1000
  guid: 0
  volumes:
    - name: data
      # emptyDir: {}
    - name: extensions
      # emptyDir: {}
    - name: logs
      # emptyDir: {}
  mounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data-2
    - name: extensions
      mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/extensions-2
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/logs-2

jdbcOverwrite:
  enabled: true
  jdbcUrl: 'jdbc:postgresql://<my_DB_endpoint>.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/sonar_sandbox?socketTimeout=1500'
  jdbcUsername: "postgres"
  jdbcPassword: <my_DB_password>

postgresql:
  enabled: false

The configMap created as a result of this helm command is not correct. It seems to be taking default values for sonar DB URL, username and password as is evidenced by this line in the pod logs:
2024.05.19 18:49:31 INFO web[][o.s.d.DefaultDatabase] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://%!s(<nil>):5432/sonarDB
As a result, the pod runs but SonarQube initialization fails. I am able to manually connect to the postgres DB using the credentials I’ve supplied in values.yaml. What could be going wrong here?
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the helm chart but it doesn't make any difference.

Is the value for jdbcOverwrite called enable or enabled? Try with jdbcOverwrite.enable=true

Yes. As I mentioned in my question about my values.yaml:
jdbcOverwrite:     enabled: true

Just asked, because here it's called enable... https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/values.yaml Line 437

use 'enable: true' instead enabled

The answer from @url3 works! But it doesn't make any sense, because they said this field is "DEPRECATED". As you can see in their source code:
## for external Databases
jdbcOverwrite:
  # (DEPRECATED) Please use jdbcOverwrite.enabled instead
  # enable: false
  # If enable the JDBC Overwrite, make sure to set `postgresql.enabled=false`
  enabled: false

I think they do have a logic issue in these pieces of code:
1 - https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/templates/jdbc-config.yaml#L4
# ...
data:
  SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: {{ template "jdbc.username" . }}
  {{- if or .Values.jdbcOverwrite.enabled .Values.jdbcOverwrite.enable }}
  SONAR_JDBC_URL: {{ .Values.jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUrl | trim | quote }}
  {{- else if and .Values.postgresql.service.port .Values.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase }}
  SONAR_JDBC_URL: "jdbc:postgresql://{{ template "postgresql.hostname" . }}:{{- .Values.postgresql.service.port -}}/{{- .Values.postgresql.postgresqlDatabase -}}"
  {{- end }}

2 - https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/blob/master/charts/sonarqube/templates/_helpers.tpl#L102
# ...
{{/*
Determine JDBC username
*/}}
{{- define "jdbc.username" -}}
{{- if and .Values.postgresql.enabled .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername -}}
  {{- .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername | quote -}}
{{- else if and (or .Values.jdbcOverwrite.enabled .Values.jdbcOverwrite.enable) .Values.jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUsername -}}
  {{- .Values.jdbcOverwrite.jdbcUsername | quote -}}
{{- else -}}
  {{- .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername -}}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
# ...

